# Add a fragment identifier in a website url

Tags: url, filter

**WHAT:**
I would like to add a fragment identifier on my site url and mantain it during the visit.

**WHY:**
The idea is to have a filter in Google Analytics that excludes the traffic whit this fragment. In this way, I can test the website from different devices without altering the results of the analyzes. By now, I´m using a subdomain to do this (test.myurl.com) but I think is better and cleaner the fragment identifier.

**EXAMPLE:**
For example, I have a new tablet and I write in it: http://www.myurl.com?id323. This fragment (?id323) is mantained during the session and all this traffic excluded from Google Analytics.

Comment: Sounds great. What's your question?

Comment: My question is:  How can I add the functionality to visit a url with a sufix (like http://www.bernatmoreno.com/libros#gaFilter) and mantain this suffix when I´m surfing in that website?
 
Maybe something like: when previous url has #gaFilter rewrite #gaFilter in next url.

Comment: @BizarriaesspumosaStudio: Please [edit] your question to include more details. We don’t know which systems you are using. What have you tried?